# Windows 2012 R2 IIS 8.5.9600.16384 and Google Go Webservice in parallel

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

My network adapters are using three IP4 addresses:

- a
- b
- c

The IIS runs two sites: A, B and the binding is

- A>a:80
- B>b:80
- B>b:443

I configured the IIS to listen to a and b as follows:

- netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=a:80
- netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=b:80
- netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=b:443

The command netsh http show iplisten shows:

- a
- b

The Google Go Webservice runs on IP4 address:

- c

Situation: This config runs fine on Windows 2008 R2. On Windows 2012 R2 it seems to run at first BUT after restarting the server the Google Go Webservice is running but the **sites A and B are stopped**. However I can start them manually and all three sites are operational again.

Approach 1: The sites A and B are running. Now I disable the Google Go Webservice and restart the service. But the sites A and B are **still stopped** after the restart.

Approach 2: (the Go Webservice is still disabled) I now add the global IP address 0.0.0.0 for the IIS to listen. So netssh http show iplisten shows: 0.0.0.0, a, b. After the restart the sites A und B are still running. However listening on 0.0.0.0 does prevent the Google Go Webservice from running because his IP and port is **now blocked** by the IIS.

Question: Why does the IIS need the 0.0.0.0 IP address to start the sites? To me this looks like a flaw in Windows Server 2012 R2. In the IIS8.5 I found other flaws as well so I would not be surprised - for example you can not use the character ? in the naming of the standard website anymore which is problematic with some of our ISAPI modules (you can write xy.dll but not xy.dll?start). What can I do now to make the three sites run simultanously? Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be enough to have a batch script start them all up after the system comes up? Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: Well, the problem is that after starting the IIS the sites are always in a stopped state. This is because the IIS needs to be configured to not listen on the IP address 0.0.0.0. So I can start the IIS and Google Go service automatically and then the batch would have to order the IIS to start the single sites A and B. But for a production system I would not trust this configuration. The sites must be guaranteed to start after the server has been restarted. Now I will rework the IP assigment of the network adapters to check for flaws in my configuration.